# python: sorting an ordered dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I create a dictionary:

```
d[1] = {'a':1, 'b':2}
d[2] = {'a':5, 'b':3}
d[3] = {'a':3, 'b':2}
```

I then try to sort by a field:

```
d = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
```

so that I can output:

```
for key in d:
    print key, d[key]
```

This sorts on 'a', but I can't figure out how to sort on 'b'. How do I sort on 'b'?

EDIT: I'm not sure how this is unclear. I'd like to sort so that the output is ordered by the values in field 'b'.

Comment: `itemgetter(1)` does not sort on `a`, it sorts on the first value, which *can* be `a`

Comment: did you try `itemgetter('b')`?

Comment: @njzk2 That won't work, as tuples don't have items like `'b'`.

Comment: Right, it's treating each entry as a tuple, and 'b' is not an index for the tuple.

Comment: Still not sure why this is being downvoted or recommended as closed for lack of clarity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modify your key function so that it explicitly returns the b value.

```
d = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (key, value): value['b']))
```

---

Edit: apparently 3.X doesn't like tuple unpacking in lambdas, so you may have to resort to the longer way:

```
d = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda key_value_pair: key_value_pair[1]['b']))
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I suppose there's no way to use itemgetter or attrgetter?

Comment: Actually tuple argument unpacking is not supported by normal functions either: [PEP 3113](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

Comment: @foosion, not that I am aware of. The problem is, the value you're trying to get is two levels deep, but ordinary itemgetters only go one level deep.