# How can I sort my JSON file by nested value?

Tags: python, json

So I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
  "PlayerA": {
    "val": 200,
    "level": 1
  },
  "PlayerB": {
    "val": 1000,
    "level": 1
  },
  "PlayerC": {
    "val": 30,
    "level": 1
  }
}
```

And I want it to be sorted by "val," so that it looks like this:

```
{
  "PlayerB": {
    "val": 1000,
    "level": 1
  },
  "PlayerA": {
    "val": 200,
    "level": 1
  },
  "PlayerC": {
    "val": 30,
    "level": 1
  }
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I think it's related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: Convert the dictionary to an `OrderedDict`. Then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533666/python-sorting-an-ordered-dictionary

Comment: JSON is irrelevant. After you load it, it's just a dictionary, it doesn't matter where it came from.

Comment: While you can order the objects for readability, a JSON object has no technical order within its keys. It is a sequence of unordered key / value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = {
  "PlayerA": {
    "val": 200,
    "level": 1
  },
  "PlayerB": {
    "val": 1000,
    "level": 1
  },
  "PlayerC": {
    "val": 30,
    "level": 1
  }
}

data = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["val"], reverse=True)

print(data)
# [('PlayerB', {'val': 1000, 'level': 1}), ('PlayerA', {'val': 200, 'level': 1}), ('PlayerC', {'val': 30, 'level': 1})]
```